# sudo prompt won't let me submit my sudo password

Tags: centos, sudo

When I ssh into my CentOS 7 machine and try to use `sudo`, I'm unable to submit my password.

Example prompt:

```
$ sudo ls
[sudo] password for edwardloveall:
```

Then I type my password, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and nothing happens. No, command is run (seemingly), no "Sorry, try again.", no nothing. I am forced to <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> out of the prompt and do something else. This failure also happens when entering an ssh key password.

Return is accepted for other non-`sudo` commands and prompts. This behavior used to work, and as far as I know the system was not updated.

How can I fix or troubleshoot this?

**Edit: Some more output to debug with:**

```
$ id
uid=1000(edwardloveall) gid=1000(edwardloveall) groups=1000(edwardloveall),10(wheel)
$ ls -l /etc/sudoers
-r--r-----. 1 root root 4188 Mar 31  2016 /etc/sudoers
```

Also tried `su -c date`, attempted to enter a password (not sure if I had the right one) but the same thing happened: no response at the prompt.

**More debug info:**

```
$ hostname
portfolio
$ cat /etc/hosts

... snip comments ...

127.0.0.1 portfolio portfolio 
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost4.localdomain4 localhost4

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 portfolio portfolio
::1 localhost.localdomain localhost
::1 localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

**Edit:**

I did find a workaround, if i hit <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> after entering my password it seems to let `sudo` work. I'd rather have <kbd>Enter</kbd> work however.

### Fix (sortof)

I found a better work around.

If I edit my `/etc/sudoers` configuration (via `visudo`) and change

```
Defaults    env_reset
```

to

```
Defaults    env_reset,pwfeedback
```

Then `*` appear when I'm typing my password, and enter works! Changing it back has the same enter-not-allowed effect as before. If anyone knows *why* this works, I'd love to know.

Comment: Could you post output of commands: `id` and `ls -l /etc/sudoers`. Can you execute `su -c date` (it requires your `root` password if exists, not the `edwardloveall` user)?

Comment: @bob Updated with suggested output

Comment: Have you changed your hostname recently? Check and post output of: `hostname` and `cat /etc/hosts`.

Comment: Sure thing. I'm _pretty_ sure that hasn't changed recently. Certainly not by me.

Comment: Try to reinstall `sudo` package: `yum reinstall sudo`

Comment: Didn't work :-/ Thank you for all you assistance by the way!

Comment: You're welcome! It seems there is an issue with your terminal, not `sudo` itself. Can you reproduce the problem in `xterm` terminal? The issue looks like `tcgetaddr()` function error, since you have no problem when force terminal to switch to `raw` or `cbreak` mode. Which output has the command: `cat /etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator | grep 'exec('` ? Try this to check and possible change your default terminal: `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`

Comment: Looks like neither of those commands work because I don't have xterm. Is it worth installing to compare with?

Comment: This seems solved for now? I'm not sure what did it but I can enter my sudo passwords again. Ghost in the machine, I suppose. Thank you again for your help and patience @Bob

Comment: Had the same issue on Arch. Unable to edit my sudoers file since neither `sudo` nor `su` work. Closing and reopening the terminal fixed it ^^